# Showing Array items in sap -select and adding an anchor tag to items

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am currently learning SAP UI5 and I couldn't find enough information about how to show  items in  `sap.m.Select`  , what I would like to do is  showing the items from my own array as a dropdown and add an anchor link to all of them like  :

```
var myMenuItems = ["foo","bar","baz"];
```

I managed to build a `Select Menu` but didnt find a way to add items, so it looks empty now.

My code for my select is  :

```
new sap.m.Select(this.createId("selector"), {
                name:"selectName",
                selectedKey: "foo",
                icon: "sap-icon://navigation-down-arrow", 
                valueState:"Success",
                valueStateText:"random text idk what for",
                forceSelection:false
            })
```

How can I push  items of `myMenuItems` and show them in this `Select`?

Comment: You need a Model containing your menu items, and then bind this model to your select :)

Comment: isnt there any functionality like repeating all the items in an array and adding it to your view ? like in Vue or Angular etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sap.m.Select is a quite powerful control. You need a model as Ash mentioned.
Here is a working example for your case:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"></script>
    <script>
        var oData = {
            MenuItems: [{id: 1,name: "foo"},{id: 2,name: "bar"},{id: 3,name: "baz"}]
        };
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
        var oSelect = new sap.m.Select({
            id: "selector",
        });
        var oItemSelectTemplate = new sap.ui.core.Item({
            key: "{id}",
            text: "{name}"
        }); //Define the template for select items
        oSelect.setModel(oModel);// set model to Select element
        oSelect.bindAggregation("items", "/MenuItems", oItemSelectTemplate); //bind aggregation with the template to items
        oSelect.placeAt('content');
    </script>
</head>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ash Kander is right, you have to create a model to contain the data.

The data binding section of the SAP UI5 SDK should show you how to do that and how to bind it to your select:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c

As a quick summary, you can create the model and set it on the Select in the onInit method of the controller associated with the view the Select is in:

```js
var oMenuItemsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  "menuItems": [
    {"item": "foo"},
    {"item": "bar"},
    {"item": "baz"}
  ]
});
this.getView().setModel(oMenuItemsModel, "myMenuItems");
```

```
<Select items="{myMenuItems>/menuItems}">
    <core:Item key="{myMenuItems>item}" text="{myMenuItems>item}" />                            
</Select>
```

Then it should work.

This is basically all taken from the code sample on the SDK:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Select/code

Comment: All of examples shown on sap page are done with using  XML view , but i must use JS view